# SQL : instead of using a union want to use a where clause but one of the clauses is only true if another clause is true

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to not use a `union` in my SQL query - how can I rewrite the following query?

```
select 
    id,
    status,
    date
from 
    table
where 
    status = 'Active'
union
select 
    id,
    status,
    date
from 
    table
where 
    status = 'Cancelled'
    and cancel_reason_id is not null
```

How can I rewrite this without the union?

Comment: OR the WHERE clause conditions. And perhaps SELECT DISTINCT is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Boolean logic:

```
select 
    id,
    status,
    date
from table
where status = 'Active'
or (status = 'Cancelled' and cancel_reason_id IS NOT NULL)
```

If you are combining with other conditions then make sure you have the correct parentheses to make it evaluate properly, e.g.:

```
select 
    id,
    status,
    date
from table
where
(
  status = 'Active'
  or (status = 'Cancelled' and cancel_reason_id IS NOT NULL)
)
and some_other_condition
```

... so you aren't caught out by [the condition precedence rules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/About-SQL-Conditions.html#GUID-65B103FE-C00C-46A3-8173-A731DBF62C80).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like

```
select 
    id,
    status,
    date
from table
where status = 'Active'
   or (status = 'Cancelled' and cancel_reason_id is not null)
```